# How to arrange different layers in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I searched many articles about convolutional neural networks and found that there are some good structures that I can refer to. For example, AlexNet, VGG, GoogleNet.

However, if I want to customize CNN architecture by myself, how to arrange/order different layers? E.g. convolution layer, dropout, max pooling... Is there any standard? or just keep trying different combination to produce the good result?

Comment: Well.... the golden question of neural networks... this is totally open to experimentation, but you may study the arrangements in the keras code for these standar models, VGG16 is quite easy to understand. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras/applications

Comment: @DanielMöller I would like to ask one more stupid question. Are the development of these standard models also experimental, so that the research team maybe cannot explain why VGG16 needs 2 Conv in the first block and 3 Conv in the third block?

Comment: It's hard to tell... maybe they can explain, maybe not.... I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me there isn't a standard per say,But combinations

1-Like if you want to create a deeper network you can use residual block to avoid facing vanishing gradient problem.

2-The standard of using a 3,3 convolution is because it reduces computational cost ex 3 simultaneous 3,3 convolution can achieve a 7,7 convolution for a smaller cost

3-The main reason for dropout is to introduce regularization ,which can also be achieved by batch normalization as the author claims.

4-Before what to enhanced and how to enhanced ,one must understand the problem he/she is trying to solve.

You can go through the case study which was taught at Standford 
[Standford case study](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAOcjicFr1Y&list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv&index=9)

The video can help you understand much of these combinations and how they result in model improvement and can help you built your network.

Comment: Off topic question. How about the pre-trained network? Comparing with CNN customization for object detection, which one can be easier and more accurate?

Comment: in terms of pre-trained network for object detection, you can chose resnet as backbone network for pre-trained CNN and go ahead with either Single stage network or Two stage network.
In terms of accuracy Two stage network have proven to be more accurate than single stage network.
1-Faster R-CNN is a two stage detector

2-Retina Net which is one stage detector but has the performance of two-stage detectors (like Faster-RCNN)

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to put a pooling layer after a convolutional layer.  Also, you can think of dropout as a parameter that is applied to a layer, and not a separate layer altogether -- whichever is easier for you to envision.

Comment: But when should I use dropout layer and based on what condition? I saw many people using it before fully connected layer. But some people added it after a few of 'Conv->Max pooling' cycle.

Comment: There is no universal guideline.  I would suggest to start simple and then try to optimize.  E.g., try dropout on all layers, or try dropout on dense layers only.

Comment: How about other layers? For example, should I add more Conv in each block or more cycle block incrementally?

Comment: You need to test out and experiment.  There is no single answer for all data sets.